# Passar valores coletados no click do botão para variável php

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em PHP e estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma tabela, a qual cada linha possui um titulo, e três botões que possuem valores, ao usuário clicar no botão 1 ou 2 o 3, preciso armazenar algumas informações como título, data, valor do botão clicado etc..

Porém ele pode fazer isso em várias linhas, ou seja, varios titulos, varias datas etc..

E ao clicar em finalizar, preciso armazenar esses valores em um array no PHP, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Se possível utilize a ferramenta do próprio Stack Overflow para desenhar a página para que possamos entender a sua pergunta.

Comment: Mostre o que já tem e o que já tentou

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é bem isso que quer mas pode ser um começo. Note que esse exemplo precisa da um parâmetro obrigatório que no caso é o valor. Você pode trocar o checkbox para seu botão se é a maneira que entendi.

**Página acao.php**

```
<?php
// recebe os valores filtrando linhas com resultados vazios 
@$titulo =array_filter($_POST["titulo"]);
@$data =array_filter($_POST["data"]);
@$valor =array_filter($_POST["valor"]);

//faz o loop para obter os dados do array (Esse exemplo só funciona com o algum valor sendo passado obrigatóriamente no caso o campo valor)
foreach ($valor as $key)  {
    @$SliceValor   = explode(',', $valor[$key]);
     $SliceValor[0]."<br>"; 
     $SliceValor[1]."<br>";
     $SliceValor[2]."<br>";

}

?>
```

**Página do formulário**

```
<form role="form" action="acao.php" method="POST">
    <?php
    //aqui vc faz o loop da sua query
    while( .... ) :
    ?>

    <!-- // uni todos valores em um array pra cada campo -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="titulo[]" value="<?php echo$titulo ?>"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="<?php echo$data?>"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="valor[]" value="<?php echo$valor ?>"/>

    <?php
      //aqui vc faz finaliza loop da sua query
    endwhile :
    ?>


    <div>
        <button type="submit">Finalizar</button>
    </div>

</form>
```